# Simple angular component doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I'm trying to implement a very simple Angular component. I expect it to output "Hello World" for the `main-windows` tag. Unfortunately it's not showing anything.

I can confirm, that webpack is working fine. I can see all my files packed in  `bundle.js` and there are not errors.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body ng-app="prj">

<main-window></main-window>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery';
import angular from 'angular';
import 'bootstrap-webpack';
import './mystyle.css';
import './mainWindow.js'

var ngModule = angular.module('prj', []);
```

mainWindow.js:
    import angular from 'angular';

```
angular.module('prj', []).component('mainWindow', {
        template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
    }
);
```

Comment: First thing I see, you are declaring the prj module twice. angular.module('prj',[]) creates the module, if you want to load it use angular.module('prj')

Comment: angular has already defined, so you should not create it again. do `angular.module('prj').component('mainWindow', {
        template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
    }
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as shown below.

*index.js*

```
var ngModule = angular.module('prj', []);
```

*mainWindow.js*

```
ngModule.component('mainWindow', {
        template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
    }
);
```

Comment: The module in `mainWindow.js` can be fetched using `angular.module('prj')`. This will remove the dependence on the global variable `ngModule`.

Comment: @musically_ut Hope it's not like that no ? Hence OP accepted the answer.